# Selenium NoSuchElementException with driver.find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

First question: How do I make python minimize chrome?

Second question: When getting to the end page using the next button how do I tell python to go on.. and not give me an error?

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/#q=" + user_input)
for n in range(5):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]""").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    posts2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")
    for post2 in posts2:
        print(post2.text)
        text_file.write(post2.text + "\n")
```

After executing this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Skid/PycharmProjects/untitled/2nd.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]""").click()
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 258, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Skid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the error? where do you get it?

Comment: @guy Fixed sorry about that

Comment: I wonder why people neg rep, yet, they don't help!

Comment: @Nevermind123 probably because you decided to not follow simple rules that are present on this site. If you want to avoid this happening in the future go read the content provided in the [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: It's fine, I just hate making new accounts every time I get neg rep, anyway, anyone know how to fix?

Comment: You get  `NoSuchElementException` on your xpath, please add the html for that element.

Comment: @guy <span style="display:block;margin-left:53px">Next</span>, This?

Comment: All the html you used to build the xpath, including the Id you used.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm new to Python and coding in general but this is how I got the XPath http://i.imgur.com/a8ZqiTZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `NoSuchElementException`, the driver can't find your element. Change your xpath to this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]").click()
```

Without 3 quotation marks.

Comment: @Nevermind123 Well, I can't really help you more without the html as I requested. (And add it to your question as text please, I'm not clicking on links).

Comment: Alright man, I'll just ask tomorrow; It's only a pastebin link but ye i'll ask later or something, probably just fix it myself somehow

Comment: One more thing you misunderstood, I have three pages (but if CAN be more depending on my search) I'm looking for awhile for it it read it, and if its not there, then do nothing.. because """ """ works.

Comment: @Nevermind123 If you want it to do nothing if its not there you should put it in `try catch` block, otherwise you will get exception.

Comment: Alright got it, thanks,     try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]").click()
    except:
        pass