# i am stuck. I am not sure for the result of the this path xPath''//a[@id='pnnet']/span[2]

Tags: python

I am stuck. I am not sure for the result of the this path

```
xPath''//a[@id='pnnet']/span[2]

driver.get("https://www.google.com/#q=" + user_input)
for n in range(5):driver.find_element_by_**xpath("""//*[@id="pnnext"/span[2]""")**.click()time.sleep(2)posts2 =driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm") for post2 in posts2:print(post2.text)
text_file.write(post2.text + "\n")
```

Comment: please add the question following stackoverflow guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Please check for duplicate questions:

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961671/selenium-nosuchelementexception-with-driver-find-element-by-xpath)

I have little idea about the problem but here is this code which scrolls through pages of the google search result of `user_input`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/#q=" + user_input)
    for n in range(5):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        posts2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")
        for post2 in posts2:
            print(post2.text)
            text_file.write(post2.text + "\n")
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem, I have exactly is what the result of this: xPath''//a[@id='pnnet']/span[2]